# Cloud Foundry Service Registry (Eureka) fails Blue-Green deployment & route paths

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I face two issues related to deploying microservices to cloud foundry with Spring Cloud Services enabled.
First, it appears that if I deploy an app with CF route path, if would simply fail to register. I deploy an app like this:

`cf push -p target/date-services-1.0.jar --hostname env5-date-services --route-path /v1 -f manifest.yml date-services-v1`

The manifest looks like this:

```
applications:
- name: date-services-v1
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  timeout: 180
  env:
    JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_MEMORY_CALCULATOR: "[memory_sizes: {metaspace: 180m}, memory_heuristics: {metaspace:  25}]"
  services:
  - rabbitmq
  - config-server
  - discovery
  - circuit-breaker
  - mysql
```

The application gets registered by Eureka, but it cannot be found. If I open the link from the Eureka dashboard, it is translated as something like:

```
http://example.com/v1:80/info
http://example.com/v1:80/date
```

This URL is simply inaccessible. Other apps try to call the date-services microservice and fail with "404 not found". If I remove the route path - from the deployment - everything is great.

The other problem is with blue-green deployments.

If I deploy the same jar to a new app name, like date-services-GREEN, again I am failing in Eureka:

```
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT 2017-03-23 07:21:16.225 ERROR [date-services-sa-v1,,,] 20 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_date-services-SA-V1/pcfdev01-date-services-sa-v1-GREEN.apps.cf.example.com:84e48618-3b11-46e4-7b3e-f638788786ea - was unable to send heartbeat!
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT 2017-03-23 07:21:16.225 WARN [date-services-sa-v1,,,] 20 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_date-services-SA-V1/pcfdev01-date-services-sa-v1-GREEN.apps.cf.example.com:84e48618-3b11-46e4-7b3e-f638788786ea - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1396)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1396)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT 2017-03-23 07:21:16.306 INFO [date-services-sa-v1,,,] 20 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_date-services-SA-V1/pcfdev01-date-services-sa-v1-GREEN.apps.cf.example.com:84e48618-3b11-46e4-7b3e-f638788786ea: registering service...
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
Thu Mar 23 2017 09:21:16 GMT+0200 (IST) [APP] OUT 2017-03-23 07:21:16.331 WARN [date-services-sa-v1,,,] 20 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient : Request execution failure with status code 403; retrying on another server if available
```

Eventually these errors go away, however after full blue-green the registered route in Eureka still points to GREEN and not the original route. Which is ofcourse inaccessible.

Here is the commands I am running:

```
cf push -p artifact.jar --hostname ${ENV_NAME}-${HOST_NAME}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-GREEN  -f manifest.yml ${TARGET_JOB_NAME}-GREEN

cf map-route ${TARGET_JOB_NAME}-GREEN ${DOMAIN} --hostname ${ENV_NAME}-${HOST_NAME}-${VERSION_NUMBER}

cf delete-route ${DOMAIN} -f --hostname ${ENV_NAME}-${HOST_NAME}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-GREEN

cf rename ${TARGET_JOB_NAME}-GREEN ${TARGET_JOB_NAME}
```

The final URL that is registered in Eureka is:

```
http://pcfdev01-date-services-sa-v1-green.cf.example.com/info
```

With the "green" in the URL, it simply doesn't work. If I remove the "green" from the URL, it works.

I've tried Camden.SR6 and Brixton SR7. Spring Cloud Services is 1.4.1.RELEASE. I Believe the runtime in the CF environment is 1.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version of the Spring Cloud Services tile is installed in your environment? For blue-green deployment of apps in the same space to work, you must be on version 1.2 or greater, see http://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-2/security-overview.html#service-registry-virtual-hostname-ownership. That section talks about apps across PCF installations, but within a PCF, you can have multiple apps register as the same Eureka appname/virtual host name, only if they are all in the same space.

For your first issue about path based routing, it is not compatible with Eureka out of the box. The app will register with the hostname+path (taken from vcap.application.uris) and this value goes into the hostname field in the registry. Ribbon doesn't expect this: https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/v2.2.2/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerContext.java#L572 You could try overriding that behaviour here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/v1.3.0.RC1/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonLoadBalancerContext.java

Another approach might be to use Zuul to map /v1 and /v2 to the correct Eureka apps, and register those the /v1 and /v2 apps with different names.

Comment: Thank you! 
Yes, it appears in that particular environment we are still on version 1.1.1-build 6. 

I wonder if upgrading would solve the first issue as well?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use a different approach other than route paths.